# Can't clone Github or Bitbucket repositories

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

When I try to clone a repository from GitHub or Bitbucket, I get an error saying "Could not resolve host: github.com" (or bitbucket.com).

I checked the global .gitconfig file, but it doesn't have an entry for http.proxy. Is it happening because of DNS issues? If so, then how to resolve it?

Comment: What is the exact url you are using to clone your repo?

Comment: Take a clone URL from any GitHub repo provided on the site, it doesn't work

Comment: The https one or the ssh one?

Comment: I am using the HTTPS one

Comment: And you can browse github.com from the workstation where you are cloning?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it happening because of DNS issues?

If you can browse github.com and look at the content of a repo through the web interface, then your DNS is fine.

Try cloning the repo with the https url, not the ssh one (since ssh can be blocked depending of your environment, meaning `git@github.com:username/arepo` won't work)

```
git clone https://github.com/username/arepo
```

but if you are using https, try the opposite, and use ssh to see if the issue persists:

```
git clone git@github.com:username/arepo
```

([generate an ssh keypair first](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys))

Comment: Not sure if it is because of DNS, just guessing as I saw several people mentioning about it on forums. I am able to browse through both Github and Bitbucket, so DNS doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: @S.RaviKiran did you try the opposite, and try to clone through ssh?

Comment: No, I will try that. But I need sometime. I will update here if it works.

Comment: When I try with SSH, it says Fatal: Could not read from remote repository